# Not getting option of metrics view in context menu of project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to use metrics view in eclipse. I followed the steps specified in  http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/    But while right clicking on project, i am not getting option  of metrics as specified.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are in the Package Explorer when you right click on the project. To see the Package Explorer, select Window -> Show View -> Package Explorer.

Comment: Even this does not work, at least in `Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2), Build id: 20160218-0600`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the Metrics? To enable, right click on your package in Package Explorer, select Properties, check the check-box "Enable Metrics" in the Metrics section.